# Setting up ImageMagick on Qt with Mac. LIBS and INCLUDEPATH

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, imagemagick, osx-leopard

I would like to build a cross platform application that will make use of imagemagick library in order to perform various actions to selected images.
I have installed the library from my terminal and as I can see,
Lib files are located at: /opt/local/lib
and include files at: /opt/local/include/ImageMagick

I tried to open the example attached here How to view tiff images in QImage and QLabel in QT 4.0

But when i try to compile it, the problem report window displays the following message

```
Path:            /Users/macmini/imageviewer-build-desktop/imageviewer.app/Contents/MacOS/imageviewer
Identifier:      imageviewer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Qt Creator [25220]

Date/Time:       2010-11-10 20:22:29.852 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          146256 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      2FA19EA1-D3CE-479B-B074-AB6A297BEFCF

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagick++.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/macmini/imageviewer-build-desktop/imageviewer.app/Contents/MacOS/imageviewer
  Reason: image not found

Model: Macmini2,1, BootROM MM21.009A.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.19f0
Graphics: Intel GMA 950, GMA 950, Built-In, spdisplays_integrated_vram
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x86), Atheros 5424: 2.0.19.10
Bluetooth: Version 2.3.3f8, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS541612J9SA00, 111.79 GB
Parallel ATA Device: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-K06
USB Device: 2.4Ghz wireless combo sets, 0x04fc  (SUNPLUS TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD.), 0x05d8, 0x1d100000
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8205, 0x7d100000
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8240, 0x7d200000
```

If I go to the Qt Application Output all I see is

```
Starting /Users/macmini/imageviewer-build-desktop/imageviewer.app/Contents/MacOS/imageviewer...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagick++.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/macmini/imageviewer-build-desktop/imageviewer.app/Contents/MacOS/imageviewer
  Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/Users/macmini/imageviewer-build-desktop/imageviewer.app/Contents/MacOS/imageviewer exited with code 0
```

the code says Image not find but as I can see, the code doesnt try to read any hard coded images.

Can anyone help me set up this ?

Where do I go wrong ?

I just want to make the library work with qt

Thank you

Comment: This error simply says, that you application can't find libMagick++.4.dylib at location /usr/local/lib/ check if library is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly Kamil Klimek  @This error simply says, that you application can't find libMagick++.4.dylib at location /usr/local/lib/ check if library is there

The file was missing. I copied and everything worked!
Thank you so much